# Pandas: improving code

Tags: python, pandas

I have a task:

Data looks like

```
id     event_path    event_time    event_duration
111     vk.com         12-12-2016       15
111  mvideo.ru/phones  12-12-2016       29
```

I need to get 5 previous unique domain before the string, where domain is `mvideo.ru`.

I use code

```
def get_domain(df, list_url, list):
    for i, url in enumerate(list_url):
        get_domain = tldextract.extract(url)
        subdomain = get_domain[1] + '.' + get_domain[2]
        if subdomain.startswith('.'):
            subdomain = subdomain[1:]
        elif subdomain.endswith('.'):
            subdomain = subdomain[:-1]
        elif subdomain.startswith('www.'):
            subdomain = subdomain[4:]
        list.append(subdomain)
    df['domain'] = list
    return df

    result = pd.DataFrame()

for i, chunk in enumerate(df):
    chunk = get_domain(chunk, chunk.event_path.values.tolist(), [])
    g = (chunk.domain != chunk.domain.shift()).cumsum()
    chunk = (chunk.groupby([chunk.member_id, g], sort=False).agg({'domain': 'first'})
      .reset_index(level='domain', drop=True)
      .reset_index()
      .reindex(columns=chunk.columns))
    cols = ['member_id', 'domain']
    chunk = chunk[cols]
    relevant = chunk[chunk.domain.isin(['utkonos.ru', 'mvideo.ru'])]
    for i in relevant.index.values:
        previous_5 = chunk.iloc[i-5:i, :]
        previous_5 = previous_5.groupby('member_id')['domain'].apply(list)
        result = result.append(previous_5)
```

I think it's not a perfect code and it takes a lot of time.
How can I improve it? What should I use or what should I learn and read?

Comment: cant you add a few more lines of data and the expected output

Comment: How about some _more_ data, along with some expected output.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
domains = pd.Series(df['event_path'].str.split('/', expand=False).str[0].unique())

first = domains.str.startswith('mvideo.ru').idxmax()

domains.iloc[max(0, first-5) : first]
```

PS from `Series.unique()` docstring:

> Return unique values in the object. Uniques are **returned in order of
>   appearance, this does NOT sort**. Hash table-based unique.